# How can I combine Fortify FPRs?

Tags: static-analysis, fortify, sourceanalyser

I am trying to combine the fprs from multiple different application scans. I have tried

```
FPRUtility -merge -project foo.fpr -source bar.fpr -f foobar.fpr
```

But that doesn't seem to do the trick. When I generate a report of foobar.fpr, I only see the results for one of the scans.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to Micro Focus's Fortify Audit Workbench User Guide and the Static Code Analyzer User Guide, you can only merge if your project contain the same analysis information. Meaning the scans must be performed on the same source code, same fortify settings, and same security content.

**UPDATE**

While the above is true regarding fprs, It is possible to merge scan results. You cannot merge fprs from different source codes. However, you CAN merge scan results and generate an fpr based on that.

In your `/path/to/.fortify/path/to/build/` you will find a directory named after your <build_id>, that directory contains intermediate files that fortify generates it's fpr off of.

You can run

`sourceanalyzer -b <build_id_1> -b <build_id_2> -b <build_id_3> -scan -f combined.fpr`

This will generate an fpr that contains scan results from different builds/applications.